# weird behavior when running git reset --hard on my local copy of a repo

Tags: git

**TLDR:** doing a git reset --hard origin/mybranch resets the local repo to a much earlier version instead of the latest one.

Dev branch looks like this:

### [image]

I think this is best explain with an example

```
[myusername@myhost myapp]$ git branch
* dev

[myusername@myhost myapp]$ git pull origin dev
From bitbucket.org:
 * branch            dev        -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.

[myusername@myhost myapp]$ git reset --hard origin/dev
HEAD is now at 2be5b0e Merged in mybranch (pull request #57)

[myusername@myhost myapp]$ git pull origin dev
From github.com:myusername/myapp
 * branch            dev        -> FETCH_HEAD
Updating 2be5b0e..2cdc555
Fast-forward
--file list here--
 19 files changed, 324 insertions(+), 196 deletions(-)

[myusername@myhost myapp]$ git log
commit 2cdc555dde1ef7ef187756036bb2d19dacae0c26
Merge: 6c9399d fc7d29f
Author: First Last <first.last@myhost.com>
Date:   Thu Jun 4 00:53:16 2020 +0000

    Merged in mybranch (pull request #81)

[myusername@myhost myappc]$ git reset --hard origin/dev
HEAD is now at 2be5b0e Merged in mybranch (pull request #57)
```

I would have thought that doing a git reset --hard origin/dev would reset the repo to the last commit (which is pull request #81)?

I also have deleted all the files and folder (including .git*) from the filesystem and recloned the repo last week. It was behaving properly for awhile and this happened again.

Comment: Could you do a `gitk --all` and post the image to understand how your branches look like?

Comment: @MondKin $ gitk --all
-bash: gitk: command not found

Updated post with a pic

Comment: `gitk` is a tool that shows you graphically how your branches look like. So it's useful to have it installed to troubleshoot this kind of problems (unless you have any other GUI tool, in which case, could you add a screenshot of that other tool? Like SourceTree or GitHub's desktop)

Comment: @MondKin is the screenshot I posted sufficient?

Comment: Stuff like this is why I recommend using a git GUI. If you're on windows, GitExtensions is pretty good. GitKraken is also good, but costs money.

Comment: @mrjayviper not enough, if you use a GUI tool you'll see how much more info it gives.

Comment: Why does the first `pull origin dev` mentions `bitbucket.org` as a remote, and the second one mentions `github.com:myusername/myapp` ? can you check the (and possibly post) `[remote ...]` sections in your `.git/config` ? @ElpieKay also correctly noted the fact that your local `origin/dev` reference does not seem to be updated.

Comment: @MondKin I cannot use a GUI tool on that server as it's a headless server.

Comment: You can try forwarding the X session: `ssh -X server.com`, which allows to open remote GUI applications sending the windows to your local machine. Besides that, maybe `git branch -a` can give you useful information, but without seeing the git tree, hard to know what's happening.

Answer (score 3):

```
[myusername@myhost myapp]$ git pull origin dev
From bitbucket.org:
 * branch            dev        -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

Here `origin/dev` is not updated. It seems `remote.origin.fetch` is not set properly. Try `git -c remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* pull origin dev` to see if `origin/dev` gets updated. If yes, run `git config remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*` so that `origin/foo` will be updated after `git pull origin foo` from then on.

Side note: in git-bash for Windows, I have experienced that `origin/foo` does get updated although `foo -> origin/foo` is not printed in the log of `git pull origin foo`, so the log is not completely accountable.